# How to allow a generic function for types that are able to be converted to String

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to use a generic function uses types (in my particular case Floats and Ints ) which are able to be created from a string.

I've noticed that both types (Int and Float) have similar init methods:
Float:

```
    @inlinable public init?<S>(_ text: S) where S : StringProtocol
```

Int:

```
    @inlinable public init?<S>(_ text: S, radix: Int = 10) where S : StringProtocol
```

So I thought to create a protocol:

```
protocol StringConvertable {
    init?<S>(_ text: S) where S : StringProtocol
}
```

So I can make both types to conform them:

```
extension Float:StringConvertable { }
extension Int:StringConvertable { }
```

And use them in my function:

```
    static func readColum<T:StringConvertable>(row:[String:String], rowIndex:Int, columnName:String) -> T? {
```

To my surprise, this doesn't compile because `Int` doesn't conform the protocol, is that because of the `radix` parameter, which is optional?!?

Is there a better way to do this, creating a protocol to group types that can be created from `String`, seems a bit code smell and probably I'm missing something here.

Thanks

Comment: If this could be done using a generic, that is how the Swift library would do it.

Comment: `protocol LosslessStringConvertible` may already be (close to) what you need.

Comment: @matt it works but I have to make an extension for Int conforming the StringConvertable

protocol StringConvertable {
    init?<S>(_ text: S) where S : StringProtocol
}

It's ugly but it works, that's why I was asking if there is a better way to do it

Comment: @MartinR that may be the possible winner, thanks! 
I've seen the conformation of Float but not for Int, but it seems to work nice, thanks!